# Bitmaps created from Video.mp4 and want to display same bitmaps as video again

Tags: android, video, android-bitmap, multimedia

MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    try (FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/storage/sdcard1/video.mp4")) {
        FileDescriptor fd = is.getFD();
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(fd, 0, 0x7ffffffffffffffL);
    }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("====>"+e);}

    for(int i =0 ; i < 99;i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i*1000000);

           //Edit Something in Bitmap.

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //Trying to display bitmaps as video in imageview.
    }
}
```

}

In this code i am able to get bitmaps from video and Using ImageView i am trying to display bitmaps again in the form of video.
Can anybody point out the problem.
or can any body suggest something for the same. by the way I am new in Android programming .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(currentFile.getAbsolutePath()) //  URI/path
            .into(image);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: How will add bitmap in that to display as video ??

Comment: You do it 30 times a second.